# Direct the camera to my location at the beginning of the application Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm starting in android, and I want to start strong, I already know a bit of java, so I decided to make a map in android. My doubt is that I try and I do not know what else to do so that when I start my application, I will have the map with the camera addressed to my location. Also I do not know if they can revizar my code, if there is some error or a suggestion, it would be incredible.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private DrawerLayout dy;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawe);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, this);
    }


    public void openNavigatorDrawe(View view){
        dy = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dy.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        UiSettings uiSettings=mMap.getUiSettings();
        // uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

        try {
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.liberte));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // ¿Permisos asignados?
            if (permissions.length > 0 &&
                    permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error de permisos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng newloc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newloc));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: give more info into what is happening when you run this code. Do you get an error?

Comment: does not give any error, the only thing I want is that when the application starts, the camera will redirect me to my location